# ODBC SQLBindCol error on Win 64

Tags: odbc, sqldatatypes, windows64

I am getting following error
 error C2664: 'SQLBindCol' : cannot convert parameter 6 from 'SQLINTEGER *' to 'SQLLEN *'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Anyone have any idea. I am also including windwos.h and have defined teh _WIN64.

Answer (score 1):

SQLINTEGER is #defined as long, SQLLEN is #defined as __int64. Therefore, you're trying to pass a long* to SQLBindCol, which takes a __int64*.